# JssorCaptionSlideo is Undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am helping rebuild a website. They have a jssor Slider on the page. 
On the old server and project it runs just fine.  I have copy and pasted the contents of those files into a new project and server. 
 So now, the page runs, but there is a **javascript** runtime error that says

> " '$JssorCaptionSlideo$' is undefined",

I didn't write any of this code, just simply trying to get it to run in a fresh solution environment.

```
<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->
        <!-- Generated by Jssor Slider Maker Online. -->
        <!-- This demo works without jquery library. -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>   
           <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.debug.js"> 
           </script> -->
                <!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
            <script type="text/javascript">

jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

      var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
        ...Bunch of machine code
      ];

      var jssor_1_options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,
        $Idle: 5000, //how long pages is idle before changing pages.
        $CaptionSliderOptions: {
          $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
          $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions,
          $Breaks: [
            [{
              d: 5000,
              b: 2500
            }]
          ]
        },
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
          $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
        },
        $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
          $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
        }
      };

      var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

    };
```

So I see where the script is trying to apply the class `$JssorCaptionSlideo$.` but it comes back undefined. `jssor.slider.debug.js`, the first `<script>` block points to, has the definition for the `$JssorCaptionSlideo$`.  I am very new to web development and I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this problem.

Is there a setting I need to enable in visual studio 2010?
Does the development server need to be configured a certain kind of way?
What Am I missing?

Just to clarify, I've literally never wrote or worked with javascript or html. So even the most basic solutions may be correct.  I was kind of thrown into this project, and it may be something fundamental that I am missing.

oh and for good measure here is where I think the definition is

```
var $JssorCaptionSlideo$ = window.$JssorCaptionSlideo$ = function (j, c, i){ $JssorDebug$.$Execute(function () { if (!c.$Transitions) $JssorDebug$.$Error("'$CaptionSlideoOptions' option error, '$CaptionSlideoOptions.$Transitions' not specified."); else !$Jssor$.$IsArray(c.$Transitions) && $JssorDebug$.$Error("'$CaptionSlideoOptions' option error, '$CaptionSlideoOptions.$Transitions' is not an array.") });
```

Comment: Can you show what line causing `undefined` in console? When you click on error, it will navigate you to the code.

Comment: `$Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,` at least that's the first occurrence of the term in the script

Comment: Is slider library that you are using referenced before this `js` code or file?

Comment: yes, it was suggested that i edit that out,but if you look above I have made a new edit

Comment: to be honest I dont know what a slider library even it is.  Is it the same as the .js that I am telling the html to open?

Comment: Just comment or remove that line and try to see if you still have that problem. The whole line `$Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,`

Comment: `$JssorSlider$ is undefined` it produces the same error but now with `$JssorSlider`

Comment: On which line? `var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);` this?

Comment: Yes that is the next line producing essentially the same problem.  The problem has something to do with the definitions not being loaded into the project, but the question is why, and how do you make sure they are loaded into the running project. (My Guess anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate your help, but as I study the architecture of the website more closely, I realize the actual problem may be in several places.  There is also a C# script associated with .aspx that helps in building the slideshow we have been trying fix. There is a strong possibility that key paths referenced in the C# script are no longer working on the new server space we are using to build the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Put the code after `<script type="text/javascript">`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

    var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
      ...Bunch of machine code
    ];

    var jssor_1_options = {
      $AutoPlay: true,
      $Idle: 5000, //how long pages is idle before changing pages.
      $CaptionSliderOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
        $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions,
        $Breaks: [
          [{
            d: 5000,
            b: 2500
          }]
        ]
      },
      $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
      },
      $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
      }
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Attempting to do this only produced more errors.  I think the problem may stemming from something other than this code right here.